# What if in $ aw^2 +c +bw =0 $ $ a,b,c $ are not real ? $ w $ is the cube root of unity.

Tags: complex-numbers

I was just solving a problem in which i was stuck that if  $ a,b,c $ are real then Is it true that if $ aw^2 +c +bw =0 $ then $ a=b=c $ ? What in case if $ a,b,c $ are not real?

Comment: As a non-real cube of unity.

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are not necessarily real, you may not have $a=b=c$. For example, you could have $a=0, b=1, c=-w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $w^2=-w-1$. Suppose that $a+bw+cw^2=0$. Replacing $w^2$ we find that $(a-c)+(b-c)w=0$.

If $b-c\neq0$, then we have that $w=-\frac{a-c}{b-c}$, and the right hand side is real: as $w$ is not real this is absurd. It follows that $b=c$ and that our equation is in fact that $a-c=0$. We thus conclude that $a=b=c$.

Comment: Is the result i got using it also true then

Comment: Sure it is.${}{}$

Comment: If you think there is some problem, you should explain what problem you think there is. Making us guess what you are thinking is not exactly a good idea, you see...

Comment: Suppose as @user8734617 said it will hold even if $ a,b, c $ are not equal like $ a=w $ $ b=w^2 $ $ c=-2 $ then putting in $ w =  - (a-c)/(b-c) $ we get w = -1 which is not true

Comment: My answer assumes the coefficients are real. If they are allowed to be any complex numbers, then **obviously** the answer to the question in your title is no. Take $c=-w$, $b=1$ and $a=0$ in the equation of your title, for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73224/discussion-between-jasmine-and-mariano-suarez-alvarez).

Comment: $ w =  - (a-c)/(b-c) $ can we write this if a,b,c are not real

Comment: If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are allowed to be non-real, then the question in the title of your question has an obvious negative answer. Just as I wrote two comments above.

Comment: Yes i believe the title has an obvious answer. I did not have a better title flashing so i asked something deviated from what i exactly wanted to know,but when we go on solving the equation for example as you got $ w =  - (a-c)/(b-c) $ we get contradictions.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don´t see any point in repeating what I already wrote three times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true. Note that $\omega^2=-1-\omega$. Therefore$$a\omega^2+b+c\omega=0\iff-a+b+(-a+c)\omega=0.$$Since $1$ and $\omega$ are linearly independent, it follows from this that $-a+b=-a+c=0$. In other words, $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 0):

For real $a,b,c$ it is true. Note $w^2=\overline{w}$ so $0=aw^2+bw+c=a\overline{w}+bw+c=(a+b)\Re(w)+(b-a)\Im(w)+c$, which then implies $a=b$, and then, because $\Re(w)=-\frac{1}{2}$: $-a+c=0$, i.e. $a=b=c$.

For complex $a,b,c$ it is not true. Take $a=w, b=w^2, c=-2$.

Comment: $ w =  - (a-c)/(b-c) $ and put the values of $a =w$ $ b=w^2 $ $c= -2$ then we get w=-1 which is not true

Comment: @Jasmine $w$ is already known... The point is that $w$, $w^2$ and $-2$ are not all equal to each other, yet $aw^2+bw+c=0$ holds. Your thinking is also correct, but requires borrowing a little from the answer by Mariano Suárez-Álvarez...

Comment: I am talking about contradiction thing. I am not obtaining w

Comment: @Jasmine Sorry, I updated my comment above.

Comment: Oh okk I see. I am very confused as to me both of you appear to contradict each other but both of you seem to be correct at your places.

Comment: @Jasmine Nope, Mariano's answer is good, no contradiction there at all! I just wanted to show on a concrete example that the statement does not hold for complex $a,b,c$. I think he has another example in his comments.

Comment: @Jasmine Note also Mariano did his work assuming $a+bw+cw^2=0$ rather than $aw^2+bw+c=0$, i.e. in his answer $a$ and $c$ are *swapped*. The way *you* wrote it, his formula turns into $w=-\frac{c-a}{b-a}$ and then you will see that there will be no contradiction.

Comment: I was completely out of mind in doing such a big mistake. I am really very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Complex roots of real polynomials are found in conjugate pairs.

If $\omega$ is a root of the polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c$ then $\bar \omega$ is also a root.
$ax^2 + bx + c = a(x-\omega)(x-\bar\omega) = a(x^2+x +1)$